# use additional cssErrorClass in Spring::Form

Tags: css, spring, validation, forms

I have this input field:

```
<form:input path="deliveryAddressFirstName" id="deliveryAddressFirstName" cssClass="text" cssErrorClass="error"/>
```

When an error during validation occurs, the CSS class of the element is changed to "error". However, I would like the CSS class to be "error text", as in: keep its regular class and add "error" instead of replacing it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with `cssErrorClass="error text"`?

Comment: Obviously that would work. However I would prefer if the errorClass would be appended to the regular class instead of completely replacing it.

Comment: Given the source code of AbstractHtmlElementTag.resolveCssClass, I don't see any possibility of doing this automatically.